# Сборка squid на Debian 9

Tags: bash, makefile, squid

Всем привет! Сразу скажу, что я ничего не понимаю в сборке, `c`, `c++` и `./configure` и `make install`, по этому хочу попросить у специалистов помощи в этом вопросе.

Хочу поставить последний [Squid 4.1](http://www.squid-cache.org/Versions/v4/) на Debian 9. Но в репозиториях его ещё нету. В связи с эти у меня два вопроса:
1. Можно ли вообще запустить Squid 4.1 под Debian 9 самому или лучше ставить то, что есть в репах?
2. При попытке собрать, получаю странную ошибку и хочу понять, что я делаю не так?

Как у меня возникает эта ошибка:

1. Имею `Linux proxy 4.9.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.82-1+deb9u3 (2018-03-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux`; работаю не под root'ом
2. Скачал `squid-4.1-20180703-r50ef141` и распаковал в отдельную папку.
3. Делаю как [здесь](https://gist.github.com/e7d/1f784339df82c57a43bf#file-squid-install-sh-L30) `./configure ...`. Только я ещё добавил `prefix=/usr ./config ...`. Ибо не понимаю смысла `--libexecdir=${prefix}/lib/squid`, когда в переменной окружения `$prefix` пустота.
4. Команда выполняется, вроде, нормально, без ошибок.
5. Запускаю `make -j1`, то всё норм.
6. Далее `make install` падает на с ошибкой `/bin/mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/share’: Permission denied` при попытке выполнить команду `/bin/mkdir -p '/share/squid/icons/silk'`

Зачем ему понадобилась папка `/share`? Для дилетанта всё выглядит так, как будь то не сработала переменная `${prefix}` при запуске `./configure`.

Подскажите плз, куда копать. Или может вообще лучше не тратить на это всё время и поставить из репы версию 3.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`make install` просит прав root, но лучше использовать [CheckInstall](https://wiki.debian.org/CheckInstall):

```
./configure ...
make
checkinstall --install=no
```

По результатам у вас появится что-то вроде `squid*.deb` , который затем ставится и удаляется штатными средствами.

Comment: А созданную им в корне директорию `/share` он потом за собой удалит?

Comment: checkinstall не будет сам по себе удалять, а dpkg удалит если может - здесь всё как обычно

Comment: Ну в целом всё сработало. Спасибо. Вот только теперь меня мучает вопрос - сколько ещё этот `make install` понасоздавал у меня в системе папок и файлов, который он удалять за собой не собирается?

Comment: И не подскажешь уж за одним, где должен появиться этот deb-пакет?))

Comment: В текущем каталоге

Comment: нету :( и ошибок в логах я тоже не нахожу

Comment: Попробуйте `find . -name *.deb`

Comment: Дропнул всё и поставил из репы. Видимо не готов я ещё к тому, что бы руками компилить всякие сервера :DD